# SQLite3 Simulate RIGHT OUTER JOIN with LEFT JOINs and UNION

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, union, full-outer-join

I have the following select statement where I need to sum each task from table tbTasks and group them by projectId from table tbProjects in order to get a record like this:

```
ProjectID = 1, ProjectName = 'My Project', TotalTime = 300 //<--sum of each task time
```

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT tbTasks.projectId, 
       SUM(tbTasks.taskTime) AS totalTime, 
       tbProjects.projectName 
FROM tbTasks 
    INNER JOIN tbProjects ON tbTasks.projectId = tbProjects.projectId 
GROUP BY tbTasks.projectId 
ORDER BY tbProjects.created DESC
```

This works and executes fine but with one problem, if a project has no task associated with it, then I get no record back at all (where I want to get projectId, projectName, and 0 or NULL for totalTime).  So, in order to right join on the table tbProjects SQLite3 forces me to do it in a round-about way.

```
SELECT tbTasks.projectId, 
       SUM(tbTasks.taskTime) AS totalTime, 
       tbProjects.projectName 
FROM tbTasks LEFT OUTER JOIN tbProjects
       ON tbTasks.projectId = tbProjects.projectId 
GROUP BY tbTasks.projectId 
UNION 
SELECT tbProjects.projectId, 
       SUM(tbTasks.taskTime) AS totalTime, 
       tbProjects.projectName   
FROM tbProjects LEFT OUTER JOIN tbTasks 
      ON tbProjects.projectId = tbTasks.projectId 
GROUP BY tbTasks.projectId 
ORDER BY tbProjects.created DESC
```

Only this does not work, I get an SQL syntax error.  What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Related: [FULL OUTER JOIN with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1923259/8583692)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even though SQLite [hasn't implemented](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) `RIGHT OUTER` or `FULL OUTER`, it **does** have `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which should do what you'd like. Just have `tbProjects` be on the left.

```
SELECT tbProjects.projectId, 
       COALESCE(SUM(tbTasks.taskTime), 0) AS totalTime, 
       tbProjects.projectName 
FROM tbProjects
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbTasks ON tbProjects.projectId = tbTasks.projectId
GROUP BY tbProjects.projectId 
ORDER BY tbProjects.created DESC
```

You get `NULLS` in `totalTime` for projects that don't have any tasks, and the call to [`COALESCE()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) replaces the null with a `0`.

Comment: is there an eval function to return 0 instead of NULL?

Comment: FYI, that fixed the issue.  I just did a variable check while I'm iterating through the query results and if null then the variable is set to 0.  Thanks for the help, I was clearly over thinking it.

Comment: @sadmicrowave: Sorry, I didn't see your second question. Yes, there is a very easy way to return 0 instead of NULL. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

From [version 3.39.0](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html), SQLite supports right and full outer join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1 RIGHT JOIN t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Thanks to Lukasz Szozda for [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72756970/8583692).