# Full Outer Join in sqlite on 4 tables

Tags: sqlite, full-outer-join

I need to join 4 tables based on a common primary key. If sqlite implemented full outer joins it might look something like this (with optimization not taken into account).

```
SELECT S.pair, C.ball, P.bluejeans, B.checkered 
FROM Socks S 
FULL OUTER JOIN Caps C 
FULL OUTER JOIN Pants P 
FULL OUTER JOIN Boxers B 
WHERE S.color = C.color AND S.color = P.color AND S.color = B.color;
```

I've looked long and hard and the best I found was this 2 table sqlite full join implemented with left joins and union alls:

```
SELECT employee.*, department.* 
FROM employee LEFT JOIN department 
ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID 
UNION ALL SELECT employee.*, department.* 
FROM   department LEFT JOIN employee 
ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID 
WHERE  employee.DepartmentID IS NULL;
```

I'm trying to modify this to work for more than 2 tables but I'm new to SQL and I'm not getting too far. Is it possible to get this result in a reasonable amount of time?

I think I have a correct implementation for 3 tables (it might not be correct) but I still can't seem to get it for 4. Here's what I have for 3:

```
SELECT S.pair, C.ball, P.bluejeans 
FROM Socks S LEFT JOIN Caps C LEFT JOIN Pants P 
ON C.color = S.color AND P.color = S.color 
UNION ALL 
SELECT S.pair, C.ball, P.bluejeans 
FROM Socks S LEFT JOIN Caps C LEFT JOIN Pants P 
ON S.color = C.color AND S.color = P.color 
WHERE S.color IS NULL;
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FULL OUTER JOIN with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923259/full-outer-join-with-sqlite)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general construction for a full outer join between two tables `A` and `B` in SQLite indeed is:

```
SELECT ... FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON ... WHERE A.key IS NULL
```

Now [create a view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) `SocksCaps` for the full outer join between `Socks` and `Caps`:

```
CREATE VIEW SocksCaps AS
SELECT ... FROM Socks LEFT JOIN Caps ON ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM Caps LEFT JOIN Socks ON ... WHERE Socks.color IS NULL
```

Do the same for `Pants` and `Boxers`.

Then treat these views just like tables and do a full outer join with the same construction:

```
SELECT ... FROM SocksCaps LEFT JOIN PantsBoxers ON ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM PantsBoxers LEFT JOIN SocksCaps ON ... WHERE SocksCaps.color IS NULL
```