# Is LEFT OUTER JOIN + RIGHT OUTER JOIN same as FULL OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Of course with the dupes collapsed.

I need to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in SQLite and it doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: did you try to cheat by joining on 1=1?

Comment: This is not the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923259/full-outer-join-with-sqlite , because SQLite does not have RIGHT OUTER JOIN, and the OP is clearly using a dialect that _does_have RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Left Outer Join 

UNION

Right Outer Join
```

They are the same.

Comment: probably want a union all.

Comment: @DanBracuk: no, the absence of ALL is actually crucial; if it is missing, the 'inner join' rows appear twice in the output.  The answers to the 'possible duplicate' question include a filter on one of the two branches of the UNION ALL query used that that specifically excludes the 'inner join' rows from that part of the union.  The filter conditions were not presented above, so UNION is correct and UNION ALL would be incorrect until the necessary filter was included.

Comment: Please note that SQLite does not support RIGHT JOIN either.