# SQL query syntax error in GRASS GIS db.execute

Tags: sql, gis

I am running GRASS GIS 6.4.1 on Ubuuntu, and I am trying to join two tables to create a new table using the following SQL query in db.execute:

`echo "CREATE TABLE landcover_new AS SELECT * FROM landcover OUTER JOIN landcover_legend ON landcover.CODE_00 = landcover_legend.CODE3" | db.execute`

I receive the following:

```
(Thu Jan 30 14:59:23 2014)                                                      
db.execute input=/home/mightyoak/grassdata/Majorca/PERMANENT/.tmp/ubuntu/2348.6 
DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
near "echo": syntax error
ERROR: Error while executing: 'echo "CREATE TABLE landcover_new AS SELECT * FROM landcover OUTER JOIN landcover_legend ON landcover.CODE_00 = landcover_legend.CODE3" | 
db.execute
'
(Thu Jan 30 14:59:23 2014) Command finished (0 sec)
```

What could be the syntax error here?

Comment: Sqlite has no [full] outer join. Use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923259/full-outer-join-with-sqlite

Comment: Are you running this directly in the shell? It seems that the whole line, including the shell intrinsic `echo`, is being passed to the SQLite driver.

Comment: I had been entering the entire line, as you said emilio, and that was the problem