# sqlite - python - full outer join with attaching a database

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, outer-join

I have 2 tables in 2 databases:

**table** `call` in `history.db`:

```
ROWID | ADDRESS | DATE 
1     | +98765  | 1396771532    
2     | +98765  | 1396771533    
3     | +98765  | 1396771534    
4     | +98765  | 1396771535    
5     | +98765  | 1396771536    
6     | +98765  | 1396771537    
7     | +98765  | 1396771538    
8     | +98765  | 1396771539    
9     | +98765  | 1396771510
```

**table** `info` in `voices.db`:

```
ID    | CALLID  | PATH       | CODE    
1     | 2       | voice1.m4a | 12234    
2     | 5       | voice2.m4a | 12234    
3     | 1       | voice4.m4a | 89765
```

First, I did an attach:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("history.db")
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("attach ? as voice", ("voices.db",))
conn.commit()
```

Then, I joined 2 tables:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM call c JOIN (SELECT PATH, CALLID, CODE FROM voice.info WHERE CODE = ?) f ON c.ROWID = f.CALLID ORDER BY c.DATE", ("12234",))
```

So, I got the following result:

```
ROWID | ADDRESS | DATE       | PATH       | CALLID | CODE    
2     | +98765  | 1396771533 | voice1.m4a | 2      | 12234    
5     | +98765  | 1396771536 | voice2.m4a | 5      | 12234
```

But, I need a full outer join to get something like:

```
ROWID | ADDRESS | DATE       | PATH       | CALLID | CODE    
1     | +98765  | 1396771532 | NULL       | NULL   | NULL    
2     | +98765  | 1396771533 | voice1.m4a | 2      | 12234    
3     | +98765  | 1396771534 | NULL       | NULL   | NULL    
4     | +98765  | 1396771535 | NULL       | NULL   | NULL    
5     | +98765  | 1396771536 | voice2.m4a | 5      | 12234    
6     | +98765  | 1396771537 | NULL       | NULL   | NULL    
7     | +98765  | 1396771538 | NULL       | NULL   | NULL    
8     | +98765  | 1396771539 | NULL       | NULL   | NULL    
9     | +98765  | 1396771510 | NULL       | NULL   | NULL
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923259/full-outer-join-with-sqlite), but I got an error of `... UNION do not have same number result columns ...`.

**How could I have a full outer Join?**

I am using Python 2.7, so

> Right and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported

Comment: The answer you linked to is correct. Show what you've tried.

Comment: @CL - I had problem with selecting from voice.info using conditions, I mean I couldn't match my code with that answer

Answer (score 2):

Your original query is badly written. Write it like this:

```
SELECT c.*, i.* FROM CALL c
JOIN voice.info i ON i.CODE = ? AND c.ROWID = i.CALLID
ORDER BY c.DATE;
```

Now transforming it into the full outer join as in the answer you linked is trivial:

```
SELECT c.*, i.* FROM CALL c
LEFT JOIN voice.info i ON c.ROWID = i.CALLID AND i.CODE = ?
UNION
SELECT c.*, i.* FROM voice.info i 
LEFT JOIN CALL c ON c.ROWID = i.CALLID
WHERE i.CODE = ?;
```

In the answer you linked they use `UNION ALL`, which keeps duplicates in the result set. I don't think you want that, so therefore I prefer to use `UNION`, which removes duplicates (rows where all the columns are equal).

Also: it's actually even better to write out all columns instead of using `*`, but I didn't do that here for brevity.

Comment: I got the following error: `Right and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported`

Comment: Thanks, But I got 2 rows like that I mentioned in my question

Comment: What does the first part of the query return? `SELECT c.*, i.* FROM CALL c
LEFT JOIN voice.info i ON c.ROWID = i.CALLID AND i.CODE = ?`

Comment: It returns those 2 rows, too. I think `UNION` does not work properly here.