# Fill a select with null when join isn't possible

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a select in n tables and show a few columns of each, but sometimes I can't match some columns and instead of getting a line with "null" the entire line is omitted.

For example:

table_a

| id | ... |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |

table_b

| id | name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | ... |
| 2 | b2 | ... |
| 3 | c3 | ... |

table_c

| name | ... |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | ... |

And then I do the following select:

```sql
select
   a.id,
   c.name
from
   table_a a,
   table_b b,
   table_c
where
   ( 1 = 1 )
   and a.id = b.id
   and b.name = c.name
```

I'm geting:

| id | name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | ... |

I'm looking for:

| id | name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | ... |
| 2 | null | ... |
| 3 | null | ... |

How do I do that? I checked a few answers around including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624927/join-columns-from-more-than-2-tables-in-sqlite-and-fill-the-missing-values-with) but I didn't get how to solve it.

Comment: You are using an ancient join syntax. Use proper joins, in this case a LEFT OUTER JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN. Your current syntax is an implicit INNER JOIN which is obviously insufficient for your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       c.name
FROM   table_a a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b
       ON (a.id = b.id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c c
       ON (b.name = c.name)
```

or, depending on precedence of the joins:

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       c.name
FROM   table_a a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         table_b b
         INNER JOIN table_c c
         ON (b.name = c.name)
       )
       ON (a.id = b.id)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (id) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'a1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'c1' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_c (name) AS
SELECT 'a1' FROM DUAL;
```

Would both output:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 |
| 2 | *null* |
| 3 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3cenIvkT)

Comment: MT0, first i thank you for organizing my question (since i'm kinda new here, i don't know how to edit it properly). Second, i want to thank you for your answer, it worked pretty well i just had to edit the order from each join as you did show.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a left join, not sure on oracle specifically but it would look something like:

```
select
   a.id,
   c.name
from
   table_a a
   LEFT JOIN table_b b ON (a.id = b.id)
   LEFT JOIN table_c c ON (b.name = c.name)
```

Comment: Dave, i tried this one but the output still the same, only the id 1.