# How to join in SQLite based on a record that is only in one of the tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, left-join, outer-join

I have one `table1` like this:

```
col1, col2, col3
A,    B,    4
C,    B,    5
```

And another `table2` like this:

```
col1, col2, col4
A,    B,    2
C,    B,    1
C,    C,    3
```

I want the result after the join to be:

```
col1, col2, col3,  col4
A,    B,     4       2
C,    B,     5       1
C,    C,     NaN     3
```

I tried a left outer join like this but it just eliminates that last tuple because `C, C` doesn't appear in the first table:

```
drop table if exists merge;    
create table merge as 
select * from table2 s2 left outer join table1 s1 on 'col2' and 'col1';
```

How do I get the desired result from a `join` operation?  Thank you.

Comment: You need to simulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` not available in sqlite. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923259/full-outer-join-with-sqlite) on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a FULL OUTER JOIN. However, this is not available in SQLite, so you need to do a workaround and do a union of two left outer joins, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923306/2947592

Answer (score 0):

First, get the set of all possible IDs by concatenating them from both tables. Then you can do a left join with both the original tables:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM (SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
      UNION
      SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2)
LEFT JOIN table1 USING (col1, col2)
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (col1, col2);
```

Comment: `Error: cannot join using column entity - column not present in both tables`, even though it clearly is in both tables.

Comment: This looks like a bug; try updating SQLite.