# Database error - RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, full-outer-join, right-join

I was trying to RIGHT JOIN two tables using this query:

```sql
SELECT Persons.firstname, company.lastname
FROM Persons
RIGHT JOIN company ON Persons.firstname=company.firstname;
```

which comes with this error:

> RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported

How can we get rid of this?

Note: I am using Mozilla DB manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FULL OUTER JOIN with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923259/full-outer-join-with-sqlite)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By doing a `left join` and switching the tables

```
SELECT Persons.firstname, company.lastname
FROM company
LEFT JOIN Persons ON Persons.firstname = company.firstname;
```

Answer (score 8):

For FULL OUTER JOIN **UNION** the result of LEFT and RIGHT( again swapped LEFT JOIN) JOIN  results...

```
 SELECT Persons.firstname,company.lastname FROM Persons LEFT JOIN company ON 
 Persons.firstname=company.firstname
 union 
 SELECT Persons.firstname, company.lastname FROM company LEFT JOIN Persons ON 
 Persons.firstname=company.firstname;
```

Comment: I think you need UNION ALL instead of UNION as explained in [Sqlite FULL OUTER JOIN emulation.](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-outer-join/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you can either:

1. Do exactly as Siddappa posted

OR

2. Use `UNION ALL` and add `WHERE Persons.firstname IS NULL` to the second select statement.  If you only do the UNION ALL without the null check, you can get duplicate rows in the result.

I think #2 is probably more efficient.