# Query to get current remaining stock in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table named `stock`:

```
name   stock
------------
 a      100
 b      200
 c       50
```

and a `sales` table

```
  name      sale
 --------------------
    a       30
    c       20
    d       30
```

The result should be:

```
name      stock
-----------------
   a       70
   b      200
   c       20
   d      -30
```

Please tell me the sqlite query for this.

My query:

```
select a.name, a.stock - b.sales as stock 
from stock as a 
inner join Sale as b on a.name = b.name
```

but how to get those name which doesn't exists in stock but exists in sales?

Comment: This requites a [full outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923259/full-outer-join-with-sqlite).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query Pleasse provide your table in SQLite syntax, i.e. "create ..." and some "insert ...". Then show what you have tried and explain what does not satisfy you.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. My mistake.

Comment: Sample data in SQLite syntax please, if you do that work, instead of expecting answerers to do it for testing purposes, you will find more favorable reactions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you want :-

```
SELECT name, sum(stock) - sum(sold) FROM
(
    SELECT name, sold, 0 as stock FROM sales
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, 0 AS sold, stock FROM stock
)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

Basically the inner SELECT extracts a table with 3 columns name, sold and stock for each combination and with 0 as the missing value. i.e. :-

[image]

This is then used as the source of the outer SELECT which groups according to name summing the sales and the stock and subtracting the sales from the stock as per :-

[image]