# Ad-hoc "joins" in Python

Tags: python, relational-database

I need to merge some data with some generated by a coworker. This reminds me of a JOIN in an SQL database, but we are not using databases, just an Excel file or .csv file for a couple of dozen entries, with a few columns each.

Is there a Python library I can use to view these data structures in an ad-hoc in-memory database and use an OUTER JOIN to merge?

example of my data:

```
Atomic symbol   Atomic number
H               1
He              2
Be              4
Si              14
Fe              26
U               92
Pu              94
```

his data:

```
Atomic symbol   Name       Hazard
H               Hydrogen   ignition, combustion
Be              Beryllium  dust is toxic
As              Arsenic    toxic
Pu              Plutonium  dust is toxic
```

Comment: pandas is the way to go

Comment: oh, that's interesting; I've never thought of `pandas` as being "database-y", but I guess data frames make sense.

Comment: You have also sqlite3 in memory db if you want to go relational. Or even a dict of dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Pandas, using [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is the most convenient method:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

my_data = '''\
Atomic symbol   Atomic number
H               1
He              2
Be              4
Si              14
Fe              26
U               92
Pu              94'''

his_data = '''\
Atomic symbol   Name       Hazard
H               Hydrogen   ignition, combustion
Be              Beryllium  dust is toxic
As              Arsenic    toxic
Pu              Plutonium  dust is toxic'''

my_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(my_data), sep='\s{2,}')
his_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(his_data), sep='\s{2,}')
joined_df = pd.merge(my_df, his_df, on=['Atomic symbol'], how='outer')
print(joined_df)
```

yields

```
  Atomic symbol  Atomic number       Name                Hazard
0             H            1.0   Hydrogen  ignition, combustion
1            He            2.0        NaN                   NaN
2            Be            4.0  Beryllium         dust is toxic
3            Si           14.0        NaN                   NaN
4            Fe           26.0        NaN                   NaN
5             U           92.0        NaN                   NaN
6            Pu           94.0  Plutonium         dust is toxic
7            As            NaN    Arsenic                 toxic
```

---

Or you could use [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), which is part of Python's standard library. `sqlite` [does not currently support FULL OUTER JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1923259/190597), however, so you would have to construct the OUTER JOIN yourself by using LEFT JOINs and UNIONs:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
from io import StringIO

my_data = '''\
"Atomic symbol","Atomic number"
"H","1"
"He","2"
"Be","4"
"Si","14"
"Fe","26"
"U","92"
"Pu","94"'''

his_data = '''\
"Atomic symbol","Name","Hazard"
"H","Hydrogen","ignition, combustion"
"Be","Beryllium","dust is toxic"
"As","Arsenic","toxic"
"Pu","Plutonium","dust is toxic"'''


with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = '''CREATE TABLE my_data
             (my_data_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
              Atomic_symbol TEXT,
              Atomic_number INTEGER)'''
    cursor.execute(sql)

    my_data = csv.reader(StringIO(my_data), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    next(my_data)
    sql = '''INSERT INTO my_data (Atomic_symbol, Atomic_number) VALUES (?, ?)'''
    cursor.executemany(sql, my_data)

    sql = '''CREATE TABLE his_data
             (his_data_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
              Atomic_symbol TEXT,
              Name TEXT,
              Hazard TEXT)'''
    cursor.execute(sql)
    his_data = csv.reader(StringIO(his_data), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    next(his_data)
    sql = '''INSERT INTO his_data (Atomic_symbol, Name, Hazard) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'''    
    cursor.executemany(sql, his_data)

    sql = '''SELECT m.Atomic_symbol, m.Atomic_number, h.Name, h.Hazard 
             FROM my_data m
             LEFT JOIN his_data h
             USING (Atomic_symbol)
             UNION ALL
             SELECT h.Atomic_symbol, m.Atomic_number, h.Name, h.Hazard 
             FROM his_data h
             LEFT JOIN my_data m
             USING (Atomic_symbol)
             WHERE m.Atomic_symbol is NULL'''
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print('\n'.join([' '.join(map('{:10}'.format, map(str, row))) for row in result]))
```

yields

```
H          1          Hydrogen   ignition, combustion
He         2          None       None      
Be         4          Beryllium  dust is toxic
Si         14         None       None      
Fe         26         None       None      
U          92         None       None      
Pu         94         Plutonium  dust is toxic
As         None       Arsenic    toxic
```

Answer (score 1):

You may load it as in-memory SQL, or use pandas.

Assume we have two CSV files as you defined above:

`/tmp/x.csv`

```
"Atomic symbol","Atomic number"
"H",1
"He",2
"Be",4
"Si",14
"Fe",26
"U",92
"Pu",94
```

and `/tmp/y.csv`

```
"Atomic symbol","Name","Hazard"
"H","Hydrogen","ignition, combustion"
"Be","Beryllium","dust is toxic"
"As","Arsenic","toxic"
"Pu","Plutonium","dust is toxic"
```

#### Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)

x = pd.read_csv('/tmp/x.csv')
y = pd.read_csv('/tmp/y.csv')
result = pd.merge(x, y, on=['Atomic symbol'], how='outer')

print(x)
print(y)
print(result)
```

→

```
 Atomic symbol  Atomic number
0             H              1
1            He              2
...

  Atomic symbol       Name                Hazard
0             H   Hydrogen  ignition, combustion
1            Be  Beryllium         dust is toxic
2            As    Arsenic                 toxic
...

  Atomic symbol  Atomic number       Name                Hazard
0             H            1.0   Hydrogen  ignition, combustion
1            He            2.0        NaN                   NaN
2            Be            4.0  Beryllium         dust is toxic
...
```

#### In-memory sql:

```
import csv, sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

def load_into_table(con, table_name, file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        dr = csv.DictReader(f)

        fields = ', '.join(['`{}`'.format(f) for f in dr.fieldnames])
        values = ', '.join(['?' for _ in dr.fieldnames])

        query = "CREATE TABLE {table_name} ({fields});".format(table_name=table_name, fields=fields)

        con.execute(query)

        to_db = [list(i.values()) for i in dr]

        insert_query = "INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ({values});".format(table_name=table_name, fields=fields, values=values)

        con.executemany(insert_query, to_db)
        con.commit()

load_into_table(con=connection, table_name='x', file_name='/tmp/x.csv')
load_into_table(con=connection, table_name='y', file_name='/tmp/y.csv')

print(connection.execute('SELECT * FROM x').fetchall())
print(connection.execute('SELECT * FROM y').fetchall())
print(connection.execute('SELECT * FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON x.`Atomic symbol` = y.`Atomic symbol`; ').fetchall())
```

→

```
[('H', '1'), ('He', '2'), ('Be', '4'), ...]
[('H', 'Hydrogen', 'ignition, combustion'), ('Be', 'Beryllium', 'dust is toxic'), ...]
[('H', '1', 'H', 'Hydrogen', 'ignition, combustion'), ('He', '2', None, None, None), ...]
```

*Note: SQLite did not support outer join.
You may emulate it: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-outer-join/*