# SQLITE: Keep all unmatched rows during join

Tags: database, sqlite, join, organization

I'm trying to join multiple tables.

Table 1:

| ID | TEMP | DESC | NUMB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 89 | Y | 6 |
| 47 | NULL | Y | 5 |
| 56 | 43 | N | 4 |
| 34 | 54 | N | 3 |
| 22 | 78 | NULL | NULL |

Table 2

| ID | IND | FLAV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | Y | G |
| 47 | N | G |
| 56 | Y | R |
| 34 | Y | B |
| 22 | Y | Y |

Table 3:

| ID | COLOR | SHAPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | RED | SQUARE |
| 47 | BLUE | CIRCLE |
| 52 | NULL | TRI |
| 22 | ORANGE | NULL |

I want the resulting table:

| ID | TEMP | DESC | NUMB | IND | FLAV | COLOR | SHAPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 89 | Y | 6 | Y | G | RED | SQUARE |
| 47 | NULL | Y | 5 | N | G | BLUE | CIRCLE |
| 56 | 43 | N | 4 | Y | R | NULL | NULL |
| 34 | 54 | N | 3 | Y | B | NULL | NULL |
| 22 | 78 | NULL | NULL | Y | Y | ORANGE | NULL |
| 52 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | TRI |

The row order of the resulting ID's doesn't matter to me.
I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 USING(ID)
LEFT JOIN Table3 USING(ID)
```

But it leaves out ID 52. I want to be sure no unmatched ID's from either table are left out.

Is this possible in SQLITE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FULL OUTER JOIN with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1923259/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement the correct type of join is `FULL OUTER JOIN` wich is not supported by SQLite.

A workaround is to use a subquery that returns the distinct ids of all 3 tables and then do `LEFT` joins to the tables with the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID FROM Table1 UNION SELECT ID FROM Table2 UNION SELECT ID FROM Table3) t
LEFT JOIN Table1 USING (id)
LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (id)
LEFT JOIN Table3 USING (id);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/61ABDyofEbKB1hFLeHfk7p/1).

Comment: Awesome I figured it out. To make it not re-list I just didn't add Table2 to the Union statement because it doesn't have unique ID's. Thank you.

Comment: @anni if you are referring to the order of the returned rows you should know that only a ORDER BY clause guarantees a specific order. Without it, the system will pick the order that the optimizer used to execute the query.